# How can I associate many alternatives to same class when defining a grammar node with treetop?

Tags: ruby, treetop

I have the following simple grammar:

```
grammar MyGrammar
  rule comparison_operator
    '=' / '>' <ComparisonOperator>
  end
end
```

When I'm parsing the string `>`, it returns successfully with:

```
ComparisonOperator
```

When I'm parsing the string `=`, it returns without syntax error, but does not associate the string matched to a `ComparisonOperator` instance, but only to a

```
Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode
```

If I reverse the order of the characters in the grammar...

```
grammar MyGrammar
  rule comparison_operator
    '>' / '=' <ComparisonOperator>
  end
end
```

then it works ok for `=` but does not work ok for `>`.

If I associate every symbol to `ComparisonOperator`

```
grammar MyGrammar
  rule comparison_operator
    '>' <ComparisonOperator> / '=' <ComparisonOperator>
  end
end
```

then it works ok for both, but I do not find that very intuitive. And it
becomes cumbersome if one has a lot of symbol alternatives.

Is there a way to associate the `ComparisonOperator` to all alternatives 
in a more simple way?

**Update:**  I have added a new Github repository with all the code that demonstrates this problem here: https://github.com/pmatsinopoulos/treetop_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Simply put parentheses around the alternatives, so the ComparisonOperator applies to either:

```
grammar MyGrammar
  rule comparison_operator
    ('>' / '=') <ComparisonOperator>
  end
end
```

The parentheses creates a sequence containing the alternates, and the class associates with that sequence.

Comment: Unfortunately. This does not work. It raises an error which I describe in the README of the problem-demo project here: https://github.com/pmatsinopoulos/treetop_tutorial

Comment: You get that error because ComparisonOperator must be a module, not a class. A class can work in some limited cases (leaf nodes), but a module is the general solution.

Comment: And why does it work if I have 1 symbol only? In my example the nodes are terminating/leaf nodes. Also, see this example here: http://glaucocustodio.com/2014/11/10/natural-language-parsing-with-ruby/ It uses a Class. Not a Module.

Comment: It must be a module any time Treetop has already created a SyntaxNode - so it can mix in that module.